# Как скрыть элемент при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

**Версия Bootstrap**: Bootstrap 4.

На сайте располагается блок с тестированием.

Тестирование состоит из отдельных кейсов, а сам кейс из четырех элементов:

1. Текст
2. Кнопка "Верно"
3. Кнопка "Неверно"
4. Картинка

При нажатии на кнопки ***"Верно" или "Неверно"*** всплывает `pop-up` окно с обратной связью. В этом `pop-up` окне есть кнопка ***"Продолжить"***.

Что нужно сделать?

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку, блок с кейсом (текст+кнопки "Верно" и "Неверно" + картинка) становился недоступным.

Например, возникла бы затемняющая плашка (поверх кейса), которая не позволит вновь выбрать ответ, или сам кейс пропадает плавной анимацией и пользователь переходит к следующему.

Как это можно реализовать?

Пример моего кода:

```css
p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #434343;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="style_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="case-1" class="col-6 mt-3">
      <p>Имя: Петрова Ирина Васильевна<br> Дата рождения: 18.01.1990<br> Место регистрации: г. Екатеринбург<br>
        <br>
        <br> Описание: автомобиль Skoda Fabia, 2011 года выпуска<br> Сумма кредита: 480 000 рублей<br>
        <br>
        <br> Срок: 9 месяцев
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                            Подходит
                           </button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Неверно!</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Клиент не подходит, потому что...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="">Понятно</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter2">
                            Не подходит
                           </button>
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle2">Верно!</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Клиент не подходит, потому что...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Продолжить</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="" alt="Ирина Петрова">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Не люблю Bootstap... Этот код, на мой взгяд, будет легче в чистом CSS реализовать. + прости, конечно, но код надо привести в порядов. Постоянно использовать `<br>` - не сексуально)

Comment: Кстати, добавь код из `style_main.css` в пример своего кода

Comment: В style_main.css есть только свойства для<p>. Остальное - BS-4 , там 12 000 строк